# Can Not Get PHP REQUEST on same page form submit

Tags: php, forms, server, http-post

I have strange issue:
I have a page which have 2 different forms on the same page. Both of the forms will submit on the same page. **I tested on local and another web-host and code worked without any problem**. ***Problem occured when I transfered files to new web-hosting server.*** When I submit **first** form, I can get POST data on the same page. HOWEVER when I submit **second** form, I can not get POST data of second post on the same page!

**Here my detections about the problem**:
1. There is no problem with the code: I have tested on 2 different sites on local machine, moreover I have tested on a different web-host it worked flawlessly, no problem!
2. In the host having post problems, both of the forms send CORRECT POST data. I watched from network section of the browser. Yes both forms SEND CORRECT post data.

HOWEVER,
- Although both forms send correct data, I can not get POST data on the for second form.

For example: for debugging purposes when I write:
`var_dump($_POST["save-products"])`: 'save-products' is the submit button of first form, it return CORRECT value.
BUT when I write same thing for the second form:
`var_dump($_POST["update-products"])`: 'update-products' is the submit button of second form, it return NULL value.

So, what's your ideas, what could cause this problem in my new web-host? Please keep in mind that code have NO PROBLEM and it is working without any problem on two different hosts. But this problem occured when I switched host!

By the way: I don't use any JavaScript or AJAX, completely PHP post and handle with PHP again.

Answer (score -1):

use:

**For 1st form submit**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_button_name'])){

    //first form php code here

}
```

**For 2nd form submit**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_button_name'])){

   //second form php code here

}
```

Comment: Yes I already handle with that way. But I just used var_dump for print out. I repeat, yes I already using with isset. And second form never isset!

Comment: @user8153977 Please improve your answer by explaining why this solution works, and how it works. Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Ok problem solved by the web-host provider. Here their response:

Dear Client,

We have increased the php memory limits and test the update form - no errors have been faced.

Please test again and if still experiencing the issue please let us know (please attach a screenshot of the issue if possible too).

NOTE: my second form post data was much larger(32KB) while first is (2KB)

Comment: By the way web-host limiting post size limit just a few KB made me upset. They even decreased below the default value!

Comment: Thanks for -1, BUT I strongly believe that this problem help people in the community. So -1 is totally meaningless, is a masterpiece of a super hero. Thanks hero